# How to group a JSON by a key and sort by its count?

Tags: json, jq

I start from a jsonlines file similar to this

```
{ "kw": "foo", "age": 1}
{ "kw": "foo", "age": 1}
{ "kw": "foo", "age": 1}
{ "kw": "bar", "age": 1}
{ "kw": "bar", "age": 1}
```

Please note each line is a valid json, but the whole file is not.

The output I'm seeking is an ordered list of keywords sorted by its occurrence. Like this:

```
[
    {"kw": "foo", "count": 3},
    {"kw": "bar", "count": 2}
]
```

I'm able to group and count the keywords using the `slurp` option

```
jq --slurp '. | group_by(.kw) | .[] | {kw: .[0].kw, count: . | length }'
```

Output:

```
{"kw":"bar","count":2}
{"kw":"foo","count":3}
```

But:

- This is not sorted
- This is not valid JSON array

A very stupid solution I've found, is to pass twice via `jq` :)

```sh
jq --slurp --compact-output '. | group_by(.kw) | .[] | {kw: .[0].kw, count: . | length }' sample.json \
| jq --slurp --compact-output '. | sort_by(.count)'
```

But I'm pretty sure someone smarter than me can find a more elegant solution.

Comment: What do you mean by `This is not sorted` ? It does appear sorted right? did you mean by sorted by descending?

Comment: To make an array just put `[..]` around the filter - `'[group_by(.kw) | .[] | {kw: .[0].kw, count: . | length }]'`

Comment: it is sorted just by coincidence. A different input would result in a more obvious unsorted output.

Comment: `group_by(.foo)`  does an internal `sort(.foo)`, so the ordering will be retained for any inputs you throw in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is not sorted

That is not quite correct, `group_by(.foo)` internally does a `sort(.foo)`, so the results are shown in the sorted order of the field. See [`jq` Manual - group_by(path_expression)](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#group_by(path_expression))

> This is not valid JSON array

Just enclose the operation within `[..]` and also the leading `.` is optional. So just do

```
jq --slurp --compact-output '[ group_by(.kw)[] | {kw: .[0].kw, count: length } ]'
```

If you are referring to sort by the `.count` you can do a ascending sort and reverse

```
jq --slurp --compact-output '[ group_by(.kw)[] | {kw: .[0].kw, count: length }] | sort_by(.count) | reverse'
```

Comment: I meant `sorted by its occurrence` not alphabetically, but based on how many times that key is present in the list.